# ckeditor server side validation for single and double quote in php

Tags: php, preg-match

I put a code for ckeditor tool, validating server side validation for single and double quotes but my code is not working.

If the string has single/double quote then it returns true otherwise return false.

Below is my code,Please have a look into it.

```
if(preg_match('/["\']/', $_REQUEST['page_description'])) {
    echo "true";
}
else {
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Your code seems correct. Perhaps, quotes are written with html entities. Note that you can do the same using `stripos`.

Comment: Works for me, could you show a sample string where it doesn't work?

Comment: normally it works, but when i am fetching data through ckeditor then it doesn't work.

Comment: hi Casimir et Hippolyte,its work for me thanks.i had found html entities and resolved it.